# How to ng-repeat this table row and increase the ng-show row position value instead of hard coding the values

Tags: javascript, html, angularjs, vb.net

I am working on a feature which allows a user to create their own table. I'd like to refactor this code.

So it creates a number of rows based on the max rows I have and also increases a row position each time without me hard coding each row.

An example of the code I have is below:

```html
<div ng-show="components.length != 0">
  <h3> Output Preview: <button Class="btn btn-primary" ng-show="components.length > 1" ng-click="hidePositionChange=(hidePositionChange ? false : true)">Change row/order position</button>
  </h3> 
<div>
<table>
  <tr>
    <td ng-repeat="component in components track by $index" ng-show="component.RowPosition == 0">{{component.Text}}{{component.Field}}</td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td ng-repeat="component in components track by $index" ng-show="component.RowPosition == 1">{{component.Text}}{{component.Field}}</td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td ng-repeat="component in components track by $index" ng-show="component.RowPosition == 2">{{component.Text}}{{component.Field}}</td>
  </tr>
...
```

Answer (score 0):

```
<div ng-show="components.length != 0">
   <h3> Output Preview: <button Class="btn btn-primary" ng-show="components.length > 1" ng-click="hidePositionChange=(hidePositionChange ? false : true)">Change row/order position</button></h3> 
   <div>
      <table>
         <tr ng-repeat="componentRow in components track by $index | limitTo: maxItems | orderBy: '+RowPosition'">
            <td ng-repeat="component in components | limitTo: 3" ng-if="component.RowPosition == $index">{{component.Text}}{{component.Field}}</td>
         </tr>
      </table>
   </div>
</div>
```

Comment: hey thanks for the reply i get this error with the orderby angular.js:469 Error: [orderBy:notarray]

Comment: Sorry, I just updated my answer, replaced '+component.RowPosition' with '+RowPosition', the key is interpreted as a property of the component in the loop. Essentially you have to pass the name of the object key as a string, by which the array should be ordered, prefixed by either "+" for ascending order or "-" for descending order.

Comment: ah cool yeah that managed to get it running however is there a way to make this table show all the objects with row position 1 in one line and then the same for line 2.

Comment: You could try applying the same logic you've demonstrated in your <TD> to the example I provided(earlier). I've made another edit to demonstrate how this could work. Notice I've replaced ng-show with ng-if to avoid creating the actual repeated elements instead of just hiding them. Im also not sure whats the max number of available items so I picked 3, you can set whatever limit you want, or no limit at all. Finally, matching the $index of the parent loop with the component.RowPosition value of the nested loop will ensure that each row only renders components with a matching RowPosition value.

Comment: Thanks for all the help. The way it is showing now is that it is repeating each row with the same value regardless if they have the same rownumber or not. it also does not show all of the data it did previously. is there a better way to rewrite what I did to work exactly the same way It works but instead of hard coding everything?